# error loading the BuildConfig: For input string: "true"

Tags: grails

my BuildConfig.groovy file

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
    grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
    grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
    grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
    grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
    grails.project.target.level = 1.6
    grails.project.source.level = 1.6
    //grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.42"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.0"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.1" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.1"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.5"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

**i am using windows xp and i'm under authenticated proxy connection. Is the problem because of the connection?**

Answer (score 5):

1 test would be to create a brand new project which will have a default buildconfig. Then to try refresh dependencies and even add a new plugin to see if you get same issue

Edited to add:

http://lalitagarw.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/grails-configuration-proxy-settings.html

GRAILS Configuration -- Proxy Settings
There are two commands to set proxy in GRAILS.

```
Add Proxy - adds a proxy server setting in proxysettings.groovy file
Set Proxy - sets the current proxy in the proxysettings.groovy file.
```

grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=4300 --username=guest --password=guest
grails set-proxy client

For example:

```
grails add-proxy myproxy --host=internet --port=8085
grails set-proxy myproxy
```

If you are using windows console then you will need to enclose parameters with double quotes.

```
grails add-proxy myproxy "--host=internet" "--port=8085"
grails set-proxy myproxy
```

Settings can then be verified in the proxysettings.groovy file. This file can be located in the .grails folder.

This was from above link, reason for adding it to post, since it has resolved a few issues so far and knowing the net things come and go. So best to include it as part of the answer here in the hope it will remain available for all.

Comment: yes, i have tested by creating a new project but the same errors show up. its a fresh install and the errors show when i running grails run-app.

Comment: well yes but run-app will download dependancies and compile code before running. Have you tried commenting out the entire config for grails.project.fork ? since I did not have this enabled on mine and attempting to use the above did not work when I ran run-app

Comment: still giving errors .. even after commenting out. is the issue due to not being able to access the repository or something? since i'm inside proxy should i set-proxy in grails?

Comment: its certainly worth a try http://lalitagarw.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/grails-configuration-proxy-settings.html

Comment: Thanks @vahid. Really strange that forgotten double quotes can corrupt the proxy settings this way. And the error message does not say anything obout this as source...