# Exception when running Grails from terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, grails, intellij-idea

I get the following exception when I try to run Grails from the terminal in OSX:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.6
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
| Error     at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:45)
| Error     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:381)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:377)
| Error     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:76)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:202)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.addRuleForModuleId(EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.groovy:135)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor$addRuleForModuleId$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.excludeForMap(EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.groovy:113)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.this$3$excludeForMap(EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor$this$3$excludeForMap.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.<init>(EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.groovy:76)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.<init>(EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.groovy:80)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies.registerDependency(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy:69)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies.registerDependencies(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy:58)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:148)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies$_createDeclaration_closure1_closure3.doCall(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy:117)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies$_createDeclaration_closure1_closure3.doCall(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.config.DependencyConfigurationConfigurer.dependencies(DependencyConfigurationConfigurer.groovy:150)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.config.DependencyConfigurationConfigurer$dependencies$1.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies$_createDeclaration_closure1.doCall(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.GrailsIvyDependencies$_createDeclaration_closure1.doCall(GrailsIvyDependencies.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.AbstractIvyDependencyManager.doParseDependencies(AbstractIvyDependencyManager.java:676)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.AbstractIvyDependencyManager.parseDependencies(AbstractIvyDependencyManager.java:577)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.DependencyManager$parseDependencies.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.DependencyManagerConfigurer.configureIvy(DependencyManagerConfigurer.groovy:157)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1281)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1219)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1075)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1053)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.loadConfigEnvironment(GrailsScriptRunner.java:249)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:210)
| Error     ... 6 more
```

I can run it fine from within IntelliJ. I know it's something with my environment configuration, but I haven't been able to figure out what, yet. Doesi anyone have any ideas?

I'm running Java:
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

OSX: 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting JAVA_HOME, I know on Linux I have to everytime I want to use grails command line..

Take a look here, maybe try updating to jdk since it does say jre .. (not a mac expert though) - also a few things to try:

http://liberalsprouts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/how-to-install-jdk-7-and-set-up.html

```
echo $PATH 
echo $JAVA_HOME


java --version
and 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

see if it is all the same.. I guess it will be, if you follow the instructions maybe see how latest jdk treats it.

to figure out what your intelliJ is using:

```
jps
3735 
7588 GrailsStarter
7660 ForkedTomcatServer
7783 Jps
```

in my case its ggts if i now run:

```
lsof -p 7588|grep -i java|grep jdk|head -n 3
java    7588  mx1  txt    REG        8,1    38568 18745123 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
java    7588  mx1  mem    REG        8,1    71084 12982357 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libj2pkcs11.so
java    7588  mx1  mem    REG        8,1    85518 18745490 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/jce.jar
```

which is -p {process id} I piped it into head to minimise output - but it gives me an idea of what jdk it is using - maybe you can trace what is going on and exports etc from using this method..

Comment: I have JAVA_HOME exported as /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home. I can't upgrade to java 7 yet since our company wide policy is java 6 (we're moving to 7 pretty soon). It's weird since it runs fine inside of IntelliJ where I'm pointed at the exact same JDK.

Comment: are you going through some form of proxy ? to gain net access usually? and is there anything configured in intelliJ for this .. if so take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973706/error-loading-the-buildconfig-for-input-string-true/18975248#18975248

Comment: No, it's not going through any proxy or anything like that. I'm thinking that it has to be a classpath issue when running from the terminal...something is configured differently. I just can't figure out what.

Comment: I gave some insight into ways of debugging what your intelliJ is doing i.e. what jdk it is using and hopefully may help give a clue as to missing class paths